# Prove that if $\{u_1 ,\dots , u_k, v\}$ is linearly dependent then $v\in\text{span}\{u_1 ,\dots , u_k\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, span

Let F be a field. Suppose $\{u_1 ,\dots , u_k\}\subseteq F^n$ is a linearly independent set,
and $v \in F^n$  does not belong to this set. Prove that if $\{u_1 ,\dots , u_k, v\}$ is
linearly dependent then $v\in\text{span}\{u_1 ,\dots , u_k\}$.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try putting the definition of a linearly dependent set?

Comment: Please format the title and question with the proper math markup.

Comment: I did the markup for you, but you must learn basic TeX (LaTeX) if you want people to understand what you mean. The .html tags do not work, and get mightily in the way.

Answer (score 0):

We can take the definition of $\{u_1,\dots,u_k,v\}$ being linearly dependent to mean that there must exist $\lambda_i$ (with $i\in\{1,\dots,k+1\}$) not all zero such that: $$ \lambda_1u_1+\dots+\lambda_ku_k+\lambda_{k+1}v=0 $$ 
Then if we suppose that $\lambda_{k+1}=0$ it's clear this would mean that $\{u_1,\dots,u_k\}$ must be linearly dependent, but this is contrary to our assumption. So we must then conclude that $\lambda_{k+1}\neq 0$ which would mean:
$$ v=-\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_{k+1}}u_1+\dots+\left(-\frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_{k+1}}\right)u_k $$
so that:
$$ v\in \text{span}\{u_1,\dots,u_k\} $$